# adding react to legacy project without using CRA

Tags: reactjs

I have a legacy javascript project with the UI layer written in jquery using MVC pattern. I want to start experimenting how to do a progressive migration to React for the UI layer only.

The project is a widget that runs embedded in a large web portal. it uses Jquery and other libraries already provided for the host portal.

The project runs some custom pre-processing, bundling, minification and deploying using good-old makefiles and shell scripts.

The host portal already includes react libraries.

My goal is to migrate a single component to react (using JSX) and bundle it, but without bundling the react library itself, as it is already available in the host environment.

also I don't want to use CRA because I want a progressive refactor, not refactor the whole project at once, and I don't feel confortable with all the stuff hidden by the react-scripts.

It is possible to use (e.g) webpack to bundle jsx components without bundling the react libraries themselves?

Comment: Does this help ? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

Comment: Use the [webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) configuration option to exclude `react` from the bundle. You can use a bundle analyzer tool to view what is included in the resulting bundle. There are several, but [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) will probably do. I find this [youtube introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAgHZ9zlmaY) was done quite well and helped me get started.

Comment: If you want you can have a look at my [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/teetotum/react-attached-properties/blob/master/webpack.config.js) in my react utility library. You can see I exclude react from the bundle and declare react as a peerDependency in the package.json (but that is not relevant for webpack).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answers, the links and the explanations! you had set me on the right path :)